# Distinct and like in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using auto complete, here problem is repeating same tuples.
Have to use Distinct with like in my code.
Here is my Model code:

```
public function get_products()
{
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['term']))
    exit;
    $data=trim($_REQUEST['term']);
    $this->db->like('Name',$data);
    $result=$this->db->get('eezy_product');
            if($result->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $result_array[] = array(
            'label' => $row['Name'],
            'value' => $row['Name'],
            'keyid' =>$row['ProductID'],
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result_array=false;
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Here is my view file :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#keyword').autocomplete({
    source:'<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/search/get_products', minLength:2,
  });
});
</script>



<div class="col-lg-2 search">
    <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/search/product">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="text" name='keyword' id='keyword' class="form-control" placeholder='Keyword'>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here in text box am getting repeated values also as auto suggest, but I  want to remove duplicates

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, have you tried searching 'distinct codeigniter'? because i found: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=distinct#CI_DB_query_builder::distinct

Comment: yeah I tried, actually the above code is from model. If I give like
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('Name');
$this->db->like('Name',$data);
$result=$this->db->get('eezy_category');
then auto complete not working

Comment: I cannot help you if you are so vague. You know more than me when it comes to what you have built. Please elaborate more on what doesn't seem to work and add it to your question. If I'm not able to help you after that, somebody else will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data=trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('Name',$data);
$result=$this->db->get('eezy_product');
```

Comment: You can rate right answer as useful or mark as true :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by name like this

```
$data=trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$this->db->select("Name, ProductID");
$this->db->like('Name',$data);
$this->db->group_by("Name");
$result=$this->db->get('eezy_product');
```

Comment: he is also selecting ProductID

Comment: I tried only distinct() but  no use with that, repeating same as above.
If am using distinct and select then not working auto suggest

Comment: @user3678396 -  check this [example](http://shivrajchari.com/blog/simple-autocomplete-function-using-codeigniterjquery-and-twitter-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$this->db->select('Name, ProductID');
$this->db->distinct('Name');
$this->db->like('Name',$data);
$result=$this->db->get('eezy_product');
```

Comment: how to get headings like, if we search products then auto suggest as so and so product in Category or in Brands.. for example check the search box in the given link below : http://www.flipkart.com/

Comment: Use `JQuery', take input on each keypress send this with `AJAX` and get products as response using db query then write script in JQuery to append products

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.